# How to call procedures in MYSQL queries

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Im having a hard time understanding when procedures should be used instead of functions in MYSQL queries. So far ive only used functions when im doing complicated queries cause they can be called in a SELECT statement but i wanted to try to use a procedure for once instead.

The procedure i had in mind chooses the value for the procedures OUT parameter which is a boolean based on some calculation. And then the SELECT statement can look at the OUT parameter and do certain things based on the OUT parameters value. Is this accomplishable? Can procedures be called in SELECT statements cause if not i really dont see the point of procedures at all except for when they are called by other functions.

Here is the full code for the procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `QualifyForGrade`(IN gradeNum INT, IN gradeSpec VARCHAR(2), OUT answer BOOLEAN)
BEGIN
DECLARE MI INT;
DECLARE MA INT;
SET MA = (SELECT max FROM grade WHERE letter = gradeSpec);
SET MI = (SELECT min FROM grade WHERE letter = gradeSpec);

IF gradeNum >= MI AND gradeNum <= MA THEN
SET answer = 1;
ELSE
SET answer = 0;
END IF;


END
```

In combination with a SELECT statement, i thought of using my procedure kind of like this but it does not seem to work.

```
SELECT ReturnStudentName(spid) AS StudentName, grade AS NumericGrade FROM stud_course
CALL QualifyForGrade(grade,'C',@answ)
WHERE CCODE LIKE(
SELECT ccode FROM course
WHERE name = 'CS Introduction')
AND answ = 1;
;
```

Comment: Stored procedure cannot be used as a rowsource of the query. Inserting into temptable seems to be the only option.

Comment: Yeah when i wrote that CALL qualiforgrade in the SELECT query i meant for it not to be a column but instead just a procedure call to get a value for the variable answ.

Comment: My rule for using stored procedures in MySQL: **never.**

Comment: If you need to obtain one scalar value then you must create/use not procedure but function. And use it by common way, like any built-in function is called. But in your case the best solution seems to be common WHERE EXISTS, without any stored object.

Answer (score 0):

Consider something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION  QualifyForGrade(_gradeNum INT, _gradeSpec VARCHAR(2))
    SELECT  gradeNum >= min
        AND gradeNum <= max
       FROM grade
       WHERE letter = gradeSpec;   -- I don't understand this
```

and

```
SELECT  *
    FROM course
    WHERE name = 'CS Introduction'
      AND QualifyForGrade('c', ???);
```